# Warning: Object defines operator == or operator != but does not override Object.Equals(object o)

Tags: c#

I'm programming in C# Unity and have really annoying problem - I want to define special Pair class with following relations:

```cs
public class Pair<T1>{
    public int First;
    public T1 Second;

    public bool Equals(Pair<T1> b){
        return First == b.First;
    }

    public static bool operator==(Pair<T1> a, Pair<T1> b){
        return a.First == b.First;
    }   
    public static bool operator!=(Pair<T1> a, Pair<T1> b){
        return a.First != b.First;
    }
}
```

Which gives me following warning:

> Warning CS0660: 'Pair' defines operator == or operator != but does
> not override Object.Equals(object o) (CS0660) (Assembly-CSharp)

But also when I spawn two objects of `Pair` type with same First integer, their `==` operator returns `True` (as I want). When I only declare Equals function, same `==` operator returns `False` value (I understand that somehow Unity compares their addressees in memory), with no warnings. Is there any method to avoid warnings and still get `True` value of `==` operator?

Comment: Once you implement `==` and `!=` operators it's advised to also override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` with custom implementations. That's what the warning is about. Most common implementations of `==` and `!=` call into `Equals` method instead of actually having any logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just override that method to make the compiler happy :

```
public override bool Equals(object o)
{
   if(o == null)
       return false;

   var second = o as Pair<T1>;

   return second != null && First == second.First;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return First;
}
```

The method you created is a custom equals method, you need to override that of the object class (which is used in the == && != operators)

Comment: This method should NOT be used, as it will throw a `NullReferenceException` when o is not `Pair<T>`

Comment: @MrAnderson I thought I added that check. Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed.

Comment: This is still not fixed. `o as Pair<T1>` will throw an error if `o` is not `Pair<T1>` but some other type.

Answer (score 3):

You need to override the `Equal`:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
    if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Pair<T1>) obj);
}
```

And the `GetHashCode` method:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        return (First*397) ^ EqualityComparer<T1>.Default.GetHashCode(Second);
    }
}
```